# andwhere doctrine 2 CURRENT_DATE IN (array(Entity))

Tags: symfony3, doctrine2, dql

Есть сущность одно из свойств которой activeDates в формате DC2type:array там хранится массив дат.
Нужно сделать запрос SELECT всех строк, у которых CURRENT_DATE() в массиве этого поля. Поле так же может быть NULL(N;)
Как правильно создать запрос в Doctrine 2 с применением DQL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
->andWhere('(e.activeDates = :null AND DATE(e.startDate) <= CURRENT_DATE() AND DATE(e.endDate) >= CURRENT_DATE())')
        ->orWhere('(e.activeDates != :null AND e.activeDates LIKE :curDate)')
        ->setParameter('curDate', '%' . date('Y-m-d') . '%')
        ->setParameter('null', 'N;')
```

Итоговый рабочий вариант

Answer (score 0):

Вам подойдёт использования "LIKE", но это не правильный подход. Те данные по которым необходимо проводить поиск не нужно сериализовать. 
Если вам нужно, что бы я и запрос написал дайте пример строки.

Запрос в формате DQL. Выведи все записи где в activeDates будет фигурировать значение CURRENT_DATE.

```
    $query = $em->createQuery("SELECT u FROM наша сущность u WHERE u.activeDates LIKE :foo");
$query->setParameter('foo', '%'.CURRENT_DATE().'%');
$query = $query->getResult();
```

Запрос формата DBLA

```
$query = $em->getRepository(Наша сущность)->createQueryBuilder('u')
->andWhere('u.activeDates LIKE :foo')
->orWhere('u.activeDates LIKE тут должна быть проверка на NULL')
->setParameter('foo','%'.CURRENT_DATE().'%')
->getQuery() 
->getResult();
```

Comment: Пример простой: нужно проверить есть ли CURRENT_DATE в activeDates через andWhere при этом учесть что activeDates может быть пустой

Comment: там большой запрос. и вроде CURRENT_DATE это функция которая выдаст ошибку в варианте %%. Так что запрос не верный. и ко всему вы просили пример. Я ж ответил через andWhere так как там еще условия идут в запросе.

Comment: CURRENT_DATE я передаю как текст.

Comment: так не работает. Так как CURRENT_DATE() должно быть.

Comment: Такие вещи нужно сразу обозначать в вопросе . Откуда я должен знать что это функция а не значение или часть сериализованного масива. Опять же я сомневаюсь что вам это поможет, я так понимаю у вас буду трудности с проверкой на null.